# Sending different push notification to each device

Tags: php, android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I have set up php script which will send push notification. Everything works fine and it sends same message to each device in array. But what bugs me is, what if I want to send different message do each device(depending on device preferences for instance)?

What would be the right approach here? My first thought is to call pushNotification function for every device separately instead of calling it once and sending array of devices to GCM?

This is the code I'm using, so please advise...

```
function sendPushNotificationToGCM($registatoin_ids, $message) {
    //Google cloud messaging GCM-API url
        $url = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';
        $fields = array(
            'registration_ids' => $registatoin_ids,
            'data' => $message,
        );
    // Google Cloud Messaging GCM API Key
    define("GOOGLE_API_KEY", "my_api_key");    
        $headers = array(
            'Authorization: key=' . GOOGLE_API_KEY,
            'Content-Type: application/json'
        );
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));
        $result = curl_exec($ch);       
        if ($result === FALSE) {
            die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
        }
        curl_close($ch);

        return($result);
}

$devices = array();

    while($results = $result->fetch_array()) {
        $devices[] = $results['dev_reg_id'];
    }

    //return $devices;

    $pushMessage = $message;

    $message = array("m" => $pushMessage); 
    $pushStatus = sendPushNotificationToGCM($devices, $message);
```

Comment: Well i am not php guy, but it seems you are passing device id and message array as argument to this function. Pass specific message with with specific device id to send notification more particularly

Comment: @ajitksharma thx. That is what I thought, to call sendNotification function for every device separately with a specific message instead I'm sending the same message for all the devices in one function call. I was wondering if that is the right approach...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't send different messages to different devices in the same HTTP request to GCM server. If each device requires a unique message, it would also require a unique call to your `sendPushNotificationToGCM` function. If some devices share the same message, you can send that message to them in the same function call.